# while loop does not increment

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

There is a weird problem my while loop is not incrementing like its displaying the first category but not the rest like this:

```
class temp 
{
var $file;

function new_list($forum_list)
{
    foreach($forum_list as $key => $value)
    {
        $this->file = str_replace('{'.$key.'}', $value, $this->file);
    }
    return $this->file;
}

function display()
{
    echo $this->file;
}
}

 $temp = new temp();

// mysql query

while ($row_cat = mysql_fetch_array($cat)){
    $temp->new_list(array(
        'CAT_TITLE' => $row_cat['title'],
        'CAT_DESCRIPTION' => $row_cat['description']
    ));

    $cid = $row_cat['id'];

    // mysql query

    while ($row_forum = mysql_fetch_array($forum)){
        $temp->new_list(array(
            'FORUM_TITLE' => $row_forum['title'],
            'FORUM_DESCRIPTION' => $row_forum['description']
        ));
    }
}
$temp->display();
```

now i have made a template engine and it uses array as usual but only displays the category its description and the subcategory and its description only once that is the first entry why is that so have i made anything wrong?

EDIT: I have added the template engine code it catches the file and use the file_get_contents method and then converts the keys to values and when i use it without the engine its works fine but with the engine it only shows the first column.

Comment: I suspect the error is that you're not really linking category to forum in $temp. Can you post the code for either the temp class or the template system ?

Comment: I have edited and posted the full code.

Comment: *blink* 1. `new_list()` returns something. 2. `new_list` does a `str_replace` on a $var, but the keys sent to it are always the same 4 keys...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to simplify it to find the error. I dont see a problem with what youve posted but I suspect theres an error in the logic of the code you havent posted. Try this:

```
<-- mysql query -->

while ($row_cat = mysql_fetch_array($cat)){
echo $row_cat['title']."<br/>";

$cid = $row_cat['id'];

<-- mysql query -->

while ($row_forum = mysql_fetch_array($forum)){
"-".$row_forum['title']."<br/>";
}
}
```

UPDATE:

Yup: Heres your problem: `$this->file = ...` is overwriting $file each iteration. You need to concat the result (add the strings together with a . ) something like this:

```
$this->file = $this->file . str_replace('{'.$key.'}', $value, $this->file);
```

Comment: Yes when i use this its works good but not with the template engine i'll edit my question and post the template engine code also. thanks

Comment: Hi @Keshav I've updated my answer for you. When error checking in future, try to simplify the code and narrow down the issue.

Comment: This time it is going more weird it first shows the values that i have entered in the html document then the title of the category then the description of the category then both the title and description and so on with the subcategories.

Comment: Sorry I didnt notice your str_replace is actually running on $this->file. Try `$this->file = $this->file . $value` and you should see it working better but probably not the way you want. As khez mentioned, your $keys are always the same so once the replace is done, there's nothing left to replace. You need to use unique keys to get it functioning as expected.